# Continue For Loop in OpenOffice Basic

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-basic

Is there a way to continue a loop in OpenOffice Basic like in other language?

```basic
For i = 0 To 10

  If i = 5 Then
     Continue For # Not working
  End If  

Next i
```

I know the Syntax *Exit For* to break a loop but I have to skip some iterations... Thank you in advance!

Comment: As @tohuwawohu said, there does not seem to be any such syntax.  See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Loops.  However with OpenOffice you can use other languages that do have this, such as Java or Python.

Comment: @JimK: Good point! Didn't think of other, feature-rich languages myself - would be worth an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't, but you also can use the `If` clause to skip certain iterations:

```basic
For i = 0 To 10

  If i <> 5 Then
     # Execute some commands except in the fifth iteration
  End If  

Next i
```

Of course, using something like `Continue` would be better style, since the `If` clause as proposed seems to handle an exception, not the normal case.

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 0 To 10

  If i = 5 Then
     GoTo Continue 
  End If  


Continue:
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, got around did by equating the iterator to itself, i.e. i = i.